# len() of a numpy array in python

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, variable-length

If I use `len(np.array([[2,3,1,0], [2,3,1,0], [3,2,1,1]]))`, I get back 3.

Why is there no argument for `len()` about which axis I want the length of in multidimensional arrays? This is alarming.  Is there an alternative?

Comment: Just apply the `len` function over each row and run `max` over that

Comment: `array.shape[i]`, with `i` indicating the relevant axis, should work well.

Answer (score 22):

What is the `len` of the equivalent nested list?

```
len([[2,3,1,0], [2,3,1,0], [3,2,1,1]])
```

With the more general concept of `shape`, `numpy` developers choose to implement `__len__` as the first dimension.  Python maps `len(obj)` onto `obj.__len__`.

`X.shape` returns a tuple, which does have a `len` - which is the number of dimensions, `X.ndim`.  `X.shape[i]` selects the `ith` dimension (a straight forward application of tuple indexing).

Comment: Beware that this is *not* the same behaviour as MATLAB. In MATLAB, the "length" of a multi-dimensional array is the length along the longest dimension (which could be calculated by `max(x.shape)` in Python). (See the docs: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/length.html .)

Answer (score 11):

Easy. Use `.shape`.

```
>>> nparray.shape
(5, 6) #Returns a tuple of array dimensions.
```

Answer (score -2):

You can transpose the array if you want to get the length of the other dimension.

```
len(np.array([[2,3,1,0], [2,3,1,0], [3,2,1,1]]).T)
```

Comment: The reason this got negative votes is that it is a convoluted way to look at things. when applying `len`, you should get length, and shouldn't have to wonder about a mathematical identity to understand what len(transpose) represents. Also, this does not work for len(arr.shape) > 2