# How to use loop in thresholding operation in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I would like to apply a thresholding operation to several grayscale images with different threshold values so that the output, which is displayed as a matplotlib plot, will be 15 or so different images with levels of threshold applied to each. The problem I am facing is that it only displays one image after it runs but if I say `print(dst.shape)` in the loop it will print 15 image shapes.

I have tried putting the output `dst` in a list so that I could access them by index `dst[2]` but this returned an error.

```
maxValue = 255
dst = []
for thresh in range(0, 255, 51):
    for img in imageB, imageG, imageR:
        th, dst = cv2.threshold(img, thresh, maxValue, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        #print(dst.shape)
        #print(len(dst))
        plt.imshow(dst)
```

What I am trying to achieve is 15 different images from the loop. Is this a matplotlib issue? Am I required to create a figure of a specific size then access each variable in the `dst` list? If so, why when I `print(len(dst))` does it only return the length of the rows in the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `figure` with sub-plots, something like this:

```py
fig = plt.figure()

step = 51
maxValue = 255
nrows = 3
ncols = maxValue // step

i = 1
for thresh in range(0, maxValue, step):
    for img in imageB, imageG, imageR:
        th, dst = cv2.threshold(img, thresh, maxValue, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        fig.add_subplot(nrows, ncols, i)
        plt.imshow(dst)
        i = i + 1
```

About your question *why when I print(len(dst)) does it only return the length of the rows in the image?*, see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081809/len-of-a-numpy-array-in-python).

Comment: What is the use of the bottom `plt.show()` here? It looks as if the `plt.imshow(dst)` accomplishes this task, yes? Also, very Pythonic way to do this and very helpful response. Will look deeper into understanding numPy arrays as I will need more knowledge on this to use OpenCV more efficiently.

Comment: @DavidAlford, you're right, last `show()` is not really necessary.

Answer (score 3):

In the code you've shown you are assigning the thresholded image from `cv2.threshold()` to the name of the list, hence `print(len(dst))` returning information about the lengh of an image rather than the length of a list. You have effectively overwritten your list with an image.

**Plotting thresholded images in a loop:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make a test image.
r = np.random.randint(0,255,10000).reshape(100,100)
g = np.random.randint(0,255,10000).reshape(100,100)
b = np.random.randint(0,255,10000).reshape(100,100)
img = np.dstack([r,g,b]).astype(np.uint8)

# Convert test image to grayscale.
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(6,2))
for thresh_value, ax in zip(range(75,255,75), axs.ravel()):
    T, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, thresh_value, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    ax.imshow(thresh, cmap='gray')
    ax.set_title(str(thresh_value))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('plot_img.png')
```

**Producing:**

[image]

Comment: Very nice.  `fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(6,2))` helps solve the next question I would look into which would be how to set subplot positions while looping. Great response!